# Read Access Logs for Email Sent from Hostway

Tags: php, email, logging, server, email-spam

Our client's Web site is Hosted at Hostway. They sent us an email regarding the site breach. They gave us this.

```
Infected Files:

Disabled:
/home/14/11/1011114/web/backup-Sept-15-2015/modules/nuSOAP/lang:
---------- 1 root root 154976 Mar 24 13:48 info13.php

/home/14/11/1011114/web/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen:
---------- 1 root root 448988 Mar 27 12:40 404.php

/home/14/11/1011114/web/losa-app-download/includes:
---------- 1 root root 10496 Mar 24 13:48 test95.php

/home/14/11/1011114/web/backup-Sept-15-2015/losa/admin:
---------- 1 root root 10816 Mar 24 13:48 session43.php
```

Evidence:

```
Spam Example:
204P Received: from sample0con by lsh1018.lsh.siteprotect.com with local (Exim 4.80)
(envelope-from <josephine_fox@sample-consulting.com>)
id 1akYj1-00033B-O3
for mrc24@aol.com; Mon, 28 Mar 2016 10:05:03 -0500 018T To: mrc24@aol.com
039 Subject: Quickie With a Girl Next Door
038 Date: Mon, 28 Mar 2016 10:05:03 -0500 056F From: Josephine Fox <josephine_fox@sample-consulting.com>
067I Message-ID: df8f0ea4b44afb61b35b27009c59c745@sample-consulting.com
014 X-Priority: 3
068 X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.9 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/)
018 MIME-Version: 1.0
085 Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
boundary="b1_df8f0ea4b44afb61b35b27009c59c745"
032 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
1akZPP-0006KC-2P-H
pcms0con 1011114 1011114
<arlene_mann@sample-consulting.com>
1459180131 0
-ident pcms0con
-received_protocol local
-body_linecount 36
-max_received_linelength 119
-auth_id pcms0con
-auth_sender sample0con@lsh1018.lsh.siteprotect.com
-allow_unqualified_recipient
-allow_unqualified_sender
-local
-sender_set_untrusted
XX
1
wahid.rotormas@gmail.com
```

I guess our site was hacked and it is now sending spam.
The email contains

> Subject: Quickie With a Girl Next Door
>
> Date: Mon, 28 Mar 2016 10:05:03 -0500
>
> From: Josephine Fox <"josephine_fox@sample-consulting.com">

We don't have any user that name and email.
Also, They gave us logs like below.

Access Logs:

```
85.128.142.15 - - [28/Mar/2016:11:17:11 -0500] "POST /backup-Sept-15-2015/modules/nuSOAP/lang/info13.php HTTP/1.0" 200 69
50.87.144.56 - - [28/Mar/2016:11:17:46 -0500] "POST /backup-Sept-15-2015/modules/nuSOAP/lang/info13.php HTTP/1.0" 200 69
72.167.190.158 - - [28/Mar/2016:11:19:15 -0500] "POST /backup-Sept-15-2015/modules/nuSOAP/lang/info13.php HTTP/1.0" 200 69
173.254.28.126 - - [28/Mar/2016:11:21:21 -0500] "POST /backup-Sept-15-2015/modules/nuSOAP/lang/info13.php HTTP/1.0" 200 69
199.182.223.68 - - [28/Mar/2016:11:23:26 -0500] "POST /backup-Sept-15-2015/modules/nuSOAP/lang/info13.php HTTP/1.0" 200 69
184.168.193.208 - - [28/Mar/2016:11:25:30 -0500] "POST /backup-Sept-15-2015/modules/nuSOAP/lang/info13.php HTTP/1.0" 200 69
93.125.99.15 - - [28/Mar/2016:11:25:40 -0500] "POST /backup-Sept-15-2015/modules/nuSOAP/lang/info13.php HTTP/1.0" 200 69
184.168.200.158 - - [28/Mar/2016:11:25:56 -0500] "POST /backup-Sept-15-2015/modules/nuSOAP/lang/info13.php HTTP/1.0" 403 15
81.17.254.94 - - [28/Mar/2016:11:27:34 -0500] "POST /backup-Sept-15-2015/modules/nuSOAP/lang/info13.php HTTP/1.0" 403 15
217.16.9.212 - - [28/Mar/2016:11:29:39 -0500] "POST /backup-Sept-15-2015/modules/nuSOAP/lang/info13.php HTTP/1.0" 403 15
```

This is where I need to focus. I want to know how to interpret this logs. As far as I can comprehend are as follows:

- 85.128.142.15 - IP
- [28/Mar/2016:11:17:11 - Date and Time of the entry
- -0500 - the web server was on US Central Summer time
- POST - Access request
- 200 and 403 - Result status code
- 69 - Bytes transferred

How to interpret this?

- **/backup-Sept-15-2015/modules/nuSOAP/lang/info13.php** - *Is this the url where the email was sent from?*
- Is that **IP** on the log where the email is sent to?

How do I know if a certain log is sending an email? Is there like a certain arrangement to notice for an email log?

Comment: Those are log entries from the http servers access log file, they describe the http requests, not email events. The requests originate from different addresses which is typical today: such zombie sites are used by distributed bot nets for their purpose. This makes identifying the people behind it much harder. The path you see in the requests is the endpoint of the API used to access the server, this looks like a SOAP API your site offers.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Last quick question, In my server logs not the access logs, how can I identify an SMTP log on which I could check who sent an email. Is it an ambiguous question? Our wordpress site has auto-responder. I want to check the emails logs and determine if a log was sent by our auto-responder or the spam. Thanks again.

Comment: I added an answer below, since the volume of the text exceeds what comments are meant for :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are log entries from the http servers access log file, they describe the http requests, not email events. The requests originate from different addresses which is typical today: such zombie sites are used by distributed bot nets for their purpose. This makes identifying the people behind it much harder. The path you see in the requests is the endpoint of the API used to access the server, this looks like a SOAP API your site offers.

The question for the SMTP log is not that trivial to answer. This actually depends on *how* your php scripts are sending the message. 4 main variants will have to be considered:

1. you operate a local SMTP server on that system which might indeed give you log files for the messages. In that case the location of the log files depends on which server software you use, for example `exim` or `postfix`. You will have to check the servers configuration files or simply dig around a bit under the folder where log files are kept, typically something like `/var/log/...`. However this variant is not very likely, since you wrote you are using some hosting company. Using a locally operated SMTP server requires to have full control over the system, so `root` access. If you had that you would know :-)
2. the messages are send using the standard route configured in php by means of phps `mail()` function. In that case it obviously depends on that configuration, to which SMTP relay server that route actually points, but it will most likely *not* be a server operated on your local system. This would mean you'd have to ge hold of the log files of that remote system operating the SMTP server. This *might* be a system your hosting company provides, but that is not very likely, since they would risk their systems to be placed on black lists again and again. Anyway, you'd have to check this with your hosting company.
3. the most likely scenario is that the messages were sent using some of the SMTP client classes available for php. Those offer a much more flexible handling of messages which is why they are usually preferred to the builtin functions. In this case the class configuration / initialization defines what SMTP server is used as a relay, so you will have to take a look into your php scripts for that information. As in option 2 this will almost certainly *not* be a locally operated server, but some typical relay like GMail or Mandrill. You won't be able to get hold of the log files then, unless you have a specific contract with those companies, which, again, you would know :-)
4. as a variant of option 3 the attacker might overwrite or replace the given configuration and provide own connection details. This most likely is possible, since apparently the attacker succeeded in executing injected code in your system. So he could do more or less what he wants. In that case you might or might not be able to find traces of those details...

---

However frankly I do not see why you are interested in those log entries or better in the information to what addresses those messages were sent.

Keep in mind that the typical attacker in such a case is not using addresses related to the attacked website. Instead usually a catalog of addresses is used that were collected by either scraping public web sites like forums (so arbitrary, stolen addresses), or by "guessing" addresses, so combining typical account names with known domain names freely available on the internet. You are not interested in that, since it is completely out if your control and not connected with you or your business at all.

Comment: Ugh! I'm on dead end. Thanks for the Reply. Truly appreciated it. I was out of options already. I have totally cleaned our sites, (update theme, plugins and change credentials, and so forth). Even Google ad-words now clear us from blacklist and yet our site is still sending emails. I've read in some forums that in the '/var/log/...' logs you can see who is responsible for sending those emails.

Comment: Wait a minute. You mean that site is still online? Take it down NOW! Even if you clean things up, you do not fix the vulnerability. For that you need to identify what is actually causing the issue and fix that (the code) or hope that the issue is fixed by upgrading php and your code.

Comment: When I read back some of my questions, It makes think back on why I asked this, and how I grow since last year. Since then I always take down sites are affected.

Comment: That reads as if you run into such issues on a regular base? That should suggest to you to think about switching the platform you build these sites on, since your current approach appears to be extremely vulnerable...

Comment: But thanks for the feedback, always great to hear that people grow using the help they receive here! Good luck!